# Formatted nested .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have some code :[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmoses5/mnwxfqgb)

```js
var array_return1 = [];

$(".table__product td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
    var productitems = $(this).html() 
         
    array_return1.push({ "Pvalue" : productitems }); 
});

alert(JSON.stringify(array_return1));
```

```html
<table class="table__product">
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>3384</td>
    <td>iPhone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Samsung</td>
    <td>8800</td>
    <td>Galaxy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LG</td>
    <td>8684</td>
    <td>V20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>8179</td>
    <td>Pixel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>4554</td>
    <td>Storm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorolla</td>
    <td>6764</td>
    <td>Z force</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to have the result set be `{Pvalue:Apple Cvalue:3384}` according to the html table. As of now I only have the Pvalue. From my research I need to use some sort of nested `.each()` function. However how would I use this and also have this format at the same time. I would like for each Product to match with it's chargetype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `tr` instead of the `td` and for each `tr` access the two `td` you want.

```js
var array_return1 = [];

$(".table__product tr").each(function() {
  var td = $('td', this),
      productitems = td.eq(0).text(),
      productId = td.eq(1).text();

  array_return1.push({
    Pvalue: productitems,
    Cvalue: productId
  });

});

alert(JSON.stringify(array_return1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table__product">
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>3384</td>
    <td>iPhone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Samsung</td>
    <td>8800</td>
    <td>Galaxy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LG</td>
    <td>8684</td>
    <td>V20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>8179</td>
    <td>Pixel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>4554</td>
    <td>Storm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorolla</td>
    <td>6764</td>
    <td>Z force</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exceptional! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are just reading the second `td` element of every row, so getting the result  `{Pvalue:3384}`

You need to iterate each row and get `Pvalue` from first cell and `Cvalue` from second cell.

```
//Iterate and create an array of object
var array_return1 = $(".table__product tr").map(function() {
  var tds = $(this).find('td');
  return {
    "Pvalue": tds.eq(0).text(), //Get text from td based on index 0
    "Cvalue": tds.eq(1).text() //Get text from td based on index 1
  }
}).get(); //To get native array
```

References [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
var array_return1 = $(".table__product tr").map(function() {
  var tds = $(this).find('td');
  return {
    "Pvalue": tds.eq(0).text(),
    "Cvalue": tds.eq(1).text()
  }
}).get();

console.log(array_return1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table__product">
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>3384</td>
    <td>iPhone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Samsung</td>
    <td>8800</td>
    <td>Galaxy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LG</td>
    <td>8684</td>
    <td>V20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>8179</td>
    <td>Pixel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>4554</td>
    <td>Storm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorolla</td>
    <td>6764</td>
    <td>Z force</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```